# how to solve this SQL and foreign language issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, procedure, persian

I wrote this procedure in a site. it take a string as input parameter(user name) and looks into the related table to find out it's record and return the "ID" field as output of procedure.
this work fine but there's one (major) problem, which is when it take a input in other English language, it can't find the target record and return "-1" as output.
The visitors use Persian language and i observed it in my SQLserver. The collation is "Persian_100_CI_AI" and my string fields are "nvarchar".
what should i do to solve this problem?
i'm using SQL-Server 2008.

thanks a lot

```
protected int GetThisUserID(string uname)
{
    string returnvalue = "";
    int returnintegervalue = -1;
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OldEagleConnectionString"].ToString());
    try
    {
        //SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT [ID] FROM [Customers] WHERE ([Uname] = '" + User.Identity.Name.ToString() + "'", connection);
        //SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Customers] WHERE ([Uname] = '" + User.Identity.Name.ToString() + "')", connection);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Customers] WHERE ([Uname] = '" + uname + "')", connection);

        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                returnvalue = reader["ID"].ToString();

                returnintegervalue = Int32.Parse(returnvalue);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message.ToString());
        returnvalue = ex.Message.ToString();
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
        SqlConnection.ClearPool(connection);
    }
    return returnintegervalue;
}
```

Comment: hey also just wondering in your code if you are only expecting ID to be returned.. then why are you selecting * from your table..? kind of costly..

Comment: please use Parameters to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: You'll need to use UNICODE as shown here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180059.aspx

Comment: @DJKRAZE KRAZE: you're write, as i used in my 1th comment line.

Comment: @dotjoe: absolutly, but 1th things first! this is a test.

Comment: @rontornambe : i believe Unicode command returns the unicode value of a charachter, why should i use it?

Comment: I suggest you try using a parameter for UNAME and set the parameter value = User.Indentity.Name (without the .ToString())

Comment: Is uname an nvarchar in the db?

Comment: @rontornambe: it's not the answer but i'm sure you're right about using parameter.

Comment: @LachlanB: as i did mention in my question: yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question but here it is:

have to add a `N` in select command, just like this:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Customers] WHERE ([Uname] = N'" + uname + "')", connection);
```

problem solved!

Without the `N`, the string is taken to be a `varchar`, and the conversion loses characters outside of that supported by the `varchar` encoding of the database.

Comment: Added an explanation as to why this makes a difference. Your code is still insecure though, should anyone decide to claim their username was `haha';delete from [Customers]; select 'haha` then you won't have any customers left. Really you should use parameters, but if you're mad keen on doing things the hard way, at least pass in `uname.Replace("'", "''")` so that you've correctly escaped the string passed in.

Comment: [It's ok to answer your own questions and accept them.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) By the way, setting the database encoding to Unicode instead of a localized encoding is always a good idea.

Comment: It'd be better to use a parameter and set it's type to `nvarchar`.